# Use the Factorization Theorem to find all the homomorphisms $\varphi : \Bbb Z_{24} \to \Bbb Z_{40} $

Tags: group-theory

Factorization theorem:
If $\varphi : \Bbb Z_{24} \to \Bbb Z_{40} $
and $\pi : \Bbb Z_{24} \to \frac{\Bbb Z_{24}}{N}$ where $N\unlhd ker(\Bbb Z_{24})\ ;\ N \unlhd \Bbb Z_{24}$
then $\exists \ \phi : \frac{\Bbb Z_{24}}{N} \to \Bbb Z_{40} \ \ \phi$ is a hom.
$\varphi = \pi(\Phi)$
I believe the kernel would be $\{[0]\}$
So $\frac{\Bbb Z_{24}}{[0]} =\Bbb Z_{24}$ which is where I'm confused

Answer (score 1):

Any homomorphism from a cyclic group is uniquely determined by its generator, in this case it is $\overline{1}$, so the homomorphisms are categorized by $\phi_k(\overline{1})=\overline{k}\in\mathbb{Z}_{40}$, where it is required that $\phi_k(\overline{0})=\phi_k(\overline{24})=\overline{24k}=\overline{0}\in\mathbb{Z}_{40}$.

So if $\overline{24k}=0\in\mathbb{Z}_{40}$, then $\overline{24k}=\overline{3k}=\overline{0}\in\mathbb{Z}_{5}$.

This implies $k=5\ell$, for some $\ell\in\mathbb{Z}$, so there are 8 homomorphisms, namely, $\phi_{5\ell}$, for $\ell\in\{0,\ldots, 7\}$.

Edit: Maybe this is more in line with what you are looking for. If you use the decomposition of finite abelian groups, you get that

$\mathbb{Z}_{24}=\mathbb{Z}_8\times\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{40}=\mathbb{Z}_8\times\mathbb{Z}_5$,

so the generator $(1,1)\in\mathbb{Z}_8\times\mathbb{Z}_3$ must be sent to $(k,0)\in\mathbb{Z}_8\times\mathbb{Z}_5$, so again there are $8$.

Answer (score 1):

The following method is essentially the same as NickC's answer.

The factorization theorem I learned is stated as following.

If $f:G\to H$ is a homomorphism of groups and $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ contained in the kernel of $f$, then there is a unique homomorphism $\overline{f}:G/N\to H$ such that $\overline{f}(aN)=f(a)$ for all $a\in G$.

That is, 
we have the following commutative diagram.
\begin{array}{rcl}
{}G & \stackrel{f}{\rightarrow}& H \\
\downarrow & \nearrow_{\overline{f}} & \\
G/N
\end{array}

(cf. Theorem I.5.6 in Hungerford's *Algebra* or Proposition 2.7.15 in Goodman's *Algebra* or Theorem 7.12 in Aluffi's *Algebra*)

Consider the homomorphism from $\Bbb{Z}$ to $\Bbb{Z}_{40}$.
You want to find the homomorphism from $\Bbb{Z}_{24}=\Bbb{Z}/\langle 24\rangle$ to $\Bbb{Z}_{40}$.
Equivalently, by the factorization theorem, 
you need (and only) to find the homomorphism from $\Bbb{Z}$ to $\Bbb{Z}_{40}$ **whose kernel contains $\langle 24\rangle$**.
Then you can know all the homomorphism from $\Bbb{Z}_{24}$ to $\Bbb{Z}_{40}$.
As the following figure indicates.
\begin{array}{rcl}
{}\Bbb{Z} & \stackrel{f}{\rightarrow}& \Bbb{Z}_{40} \\
\downarrow & \nearrow_{\overline{f}} & \\
\Bbb{Z}_{24}\cong \Bbb{Z}/\langle 24\rangle
\end{array}
$$\langle 24\rangle\subseteq \ker{f}
\Leftrightarrow 24f(1)=f(24)=0\in \Bbb{Z}_{40}
\Leftrightarrow 40\mid 24 f(1)
\Leftrightarrow 5\mid f(1).$$
There are $40$ homomorphisms from $\Bbb{Z}$ to $\Bbb{Z}_{40}$.
$8$ of them satisfy $5\mid f(1)$.
That is, $f(1)\in \{0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35\}$.